# How can constant creation of new stars explained theologically?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, science, creation, astronomy

> "... we get on average about one new star per year, and one star dying each year as a planetary nebula in the Milky Way.... therefore **there are about 275 million [born] per day**, in the whole observable Universe. ([from cornell.edu](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/83-the-universe/stars-and-star-clusters/star-formation-and-molecular-clouds/400-how-many-stars-are-born-and-die-each-day-beginner))

How can this phenomenon be explained in Judaism, where, seemingly, G-d ceased creation of heavenly bodies on the 4th day?

Comment: What about vegetation, animals, people, etc.?

Comment: Please see my comment to SabbaHillel in his answer. Also, I don't understand  why this question is receiving down votes. It's fine and also on topic.

Comment: It could be that G-d created the big bang and allowed nature to take command. Or, it could be that new animals and people are a creation every day, including stars.

Comment: From where do you see that G-d ceased creation of heavenly bodies?

Comment: How can constant creation of new humans and animals be explained theologically? The question does not make sense.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I'm very *sorry* to see how flexible we are in our interpretations, you just pull a phrase saying "new" and "creation" in the same breath and think it explains everything. This isn't our tradition - sabba just cited Rashi that everything was created in the original creation. That was our stand through 200 years, until we realized how wrong we are.

Comment: @AlBerko "everything was created in the original creation. That was our stand through 200 years" is clearly incorrect, in the sense that you're using it. As Alex and Jonathan point out, no one disputes that many individual organisms, for example, have come into being since Creation. Stars being born from the coalescence of cosmic gases ought to be no different, philosophically, from trees sprouting from seeds and an accumulation of matter from the environment.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I meant 2000. I explained already that nobody in Judaism held the opinion that the celestial bodies are physical, see Rambams Yesodot (Aristotle).

Comment: @IsaacMoses Love the change to your avatar, although it's barely readable. Any word on that front?

Comment: @YaacovDeane [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334417/179) on MSE is doing a pretty good job of chronicling the major events

Comment: Are you asking regarding a literal reading of some unspecified verse in Genesis? Or regarding (a literal reading of) some unspecified ancient commentary?

Comment: This seems like a question of how does Torah fit with modern science. But even without modern science we could have asked the question, because there were always comets (and meteors) that are "new stars" which appear every so often. We say on them the beracha of עשה מעשה בראשית, but we knew that some stars are new.

Answer (score 8):

They are not *created*, they are formed by means of the natural laws from preexisting matter. This has nothing to do with *yesh mai-ayin* (creation from nothing) which occurred at the very beginning.

> We usually talk of star formation in terms of the gas mass that is converted
>   into stars each year.

Indeed as Rashi and others point out on [Bereishis 1:14](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165/showrashi/true#v14) *Yesh mai-ayin* could have occurred only at the very beginning and that all other *creations* were formed upon the command of Hashem at the beginning of each *day* from the now existing primordial material..

> And God said, "Let there be luminaries in the expanse of the heavens,
>   to separate between the day and between the night, and they shall be
>   for signs and for appointed seasons and for days and years.

As Rashi said

> **Let there be luminaries, etc.:** They were created on the first day,
>   and on the fourth day, He commanded them to be suspended in the sky,
>   and likewise, all the creations of heaven and earth were created on
>   the first day, and each one was fixed in its proper place on the day
>   that was decreed upon it. That is why it is written:“with the heavens
>   (אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם) to include their products,”and with the earth (וְאֵת
>   הָאָרֶץ)," to include its products. — [Gen. Rabbah 1:14]

Comment: You are right on target, SabbaHillel. You should consider including the blessing from before morning Shema, "המחדש בטובו  בכל יום תמיד מעשה בראשית כו׳". It is extremely relevant to what you have in your answer.

Comment: @Loewian This is a general understanding related to everything in the six days of creations. The first 'Yesh miYesh' mentioned explicitly was Chava.

Comment: @sabbahillel That's the meaning of the posuk we say in the blessing cited in my comment to you. All Jews who recite the blessings for Shema declare this every day.

Comment: How smart we are after somebody else discovered it. This isn't and never was the official Jewish stand - we sincerely believed what Rashi (Midrash) said - everything was created on the first round. You completely forget Rambam (Aristo) that claims that the celestial bodies are nothing physical - they are spiritual beings, so they are definitely not "born from dust".

Comment: @AlBerko Where does the Rambam day this

Comment: @sabbahillel "They are not created, they are born by means of the natural laws" A better choice of English word would be "they are formed by means of the natural laws..." This is the same type of distinction made in the text of the 'יוצר אור ובורא חשך' prayer. Creation refers to Yesh miAyin, like you say. Yesh miYesh is referred to as formation.

Comment: @sabbahillel AlBerko is misunderstanding what the Rambam is writing in Hilchot Yesodei HaTorah Chapter 2:3. Rambam does not say that the 'celestial bodies', meaning the planets and stars, are completely spiritual beings.

Comment: "All the stars and spheres possess a soul, knowledge, and intellect. They are alive and stand in recognition of the One who spoke and [thus brought] the world into being.
According to their size and level, each one praises and glorifies their Creator as the angels do.12 Just as they are aware of the Holy One, blessed be He, they are also aware of themselves and of the angels which surpass them. The knowledge of the stars and the spheres is less than the knowledge of the angels, but greater than that of men.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904969/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Three.htm

Comment: @YaacovDeane So you're saying, because they are alive they procreate?

Comment: @AlBerko Read in Hebrew (and carefully, take the time to understand the words) the 3rd sentence of the Rambam I cite in my previous comment directed to sabbahillel. They don't procreate. They are essentially unchanging. You would think of them as 'Domem'. But Rambam emphasizes that they are also alive and intelligent. The Ari z"l says this too.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Oh, thank you, just kidding. So how are they born if they are alive?

Comment: @AlBerko Looking at your link to the Chabad site, you are looking at chapter 3 of Yesodei HaTorah, not chapter 2. It is discussing the 'Galgalim', not the stars and planets. The 'Galgalim' are heavenly boundaries and are not comprised of material substance at all. Like I said above, you are misunderstanding what the Rambam is discussing.